# How to show different clock from different time zones in iPhone app

Tags: iphone

In my app I want to show timings of different countries like
Japan
UK
USA
France
    how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current date by,

```
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
```

Then using `NSTimezone` get the timings for different countries.

Sample code

```
NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"JST"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate] autorelease];
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for your replay, but can u please tell me if I want to get the current time of France and Japan . what I have to do, I mean which TimeZone I should select.

Comment: u can change the timezone using,  [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, actually I have never worked on this topic so if you can give me a link for a sample code based on NSTimeZone then that will be helpful but its nor necessary. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code from apple related to time zones

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Man dont duplicate questions. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376311/how-to-display-time-of-major-countries-of-world/4376762#4376762

Comment: @ya I know, actually I was not getting any reply on that question and i thought may i am not clear so I putted same question  with new words, i understand what u r trying to say.

Comment: I have deleted my previous question