# Can any one help me to display current time zone in a label?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Can any one help me to display current time zone in a label in xcode(objective-c)?

I tried the following and have been trying to assign it to a label:

```
NSArray *timezoneList = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: knownTimeZoneNames returns names of all the timezones known to the system in an array. You want [NSTimeZone localTimeZone], and then set the text property of the label to the description of that object. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current timezone with `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]`. So if you have your label as an IBOutlet in a view controller you can do

```
label.text = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] description];
```

Comment: I've one more query with the local time zone I need to display list of time zones separately to select one of them, and select time according  it.

Comment: The code in this answer is probably a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376585/how-to-show-different-clock-from-different-time-zones-in-iphone-app